# How to find database name in oracle without using sqlplus or srvctl?

Tags: oracle, oracle-rac

I want to know different ways to find the database name without making connection to the database, neither using `sqlplus` or `srvctl`

In oracle, let's suppose I have 2 nodes in a RAC running the database `pstest`. I can get the database name by simply connecting to any one of the db instance and query as below

```
SQL> select name from v$database;
NAME
---------
PSTEST
```

or

```
SQL> show parameter db_name
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_name                              string      pstest`
```

But I need to know how can I get the database name which is `pstest` here without connecting to the database by `sqlplus` (so both above won't be useful).

As my `pstest` database is running in 2 instances - `pstest1` on node1  and `pstest2` on node2. So I can use srvctl as below

```
  srvctl status database -d pstest
  Instance pstest1 is running on node1
  Instance pstest2 is running on node2
```

But how can I get `<db_name>` to use to in `srvctl` without using `srvctl` or `sqlplus` ?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: do you have more than one database running in this RAC ??

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice after the first one was closed. Edit the first question to improve it and then ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: @MTO, I think it might be reopened. He wants a way to get it inside the cluster without using `sqlplus` or `srvctl`

Comment: maybe check the entries in /etc/oratab

Comment: @Sharvani R, I vote to reopen, but I don't have the privilege to do it by myself. More people needs to vote for it. There is a way to do it without using `sqlplus` nor `srvctl`

Comment: It may help to explain why you're asking this.  There are ways to try to figure out what databases are running on a particular server but there are issues with any of the methods so we need to understand what problem you're trying to solve.  For example, you can grep running processes on a Unix box if you are sure that the database is up and running.  If you're writing monitoring software, though, ignoring databases that aren't running is probably a bad idea.  You could look at /etc/oratab because conventionally that'll have information but it isn't required.

Comment: Thank you all.
@RobertoHernandez In RAC , only single database running on 2 instances. and yes as you said I need a way to do it without `sqlplus` but about `srvctl` to make it clear , to run `srvctl status database -d <db_name>` I need to provide the db_name right , for that case I wanted  to know the db_name without sqlplus. I think I made it clear?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO @Justine Cave to use /etc/oratab , Can I manually enter any new env var say ORACLE_DB_NAME and set with the name , and fetch that env inside a shell script to use it for running `srvctl status database -d $ORACLE_DB_NAME` ?

Comment: Also to give one more use case:I have a shell script test.sh , which will fetch db_name and use that in srvctl `srvctl start instance -d <db_name> -i <instance_name>`
I can simply get a db_name from ORACLE_SID -> ${ORACLE_SID%?} by stripping **last char of sid**. `Instance 1 = ORACLE_SID = pstest1` -> `db_name= pstest`
But the above doesn't work if I have more than 9 instances running 
`Instance 10 = ORACLE_SID = pstest10` --> to get `db_name = ${ORACLE_SID%?} = pstest1` --> ideally should be `pstest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without even understanding why you'd need this, which is kind of odd, a way to do this would be ( keeping in consideration that you are using `Oracle RAC` )

The utility in this case is `csrsctl`

Example

```
srvctl status database -d otcgr2ng
Instance otcgr2ng1 is running on node scglvdoraci0009
Instance otcgr2ng2 is running on node scglvdoraci0010
db_name=$(crsctl stat res -t | grep ".db$" | grep -v mgmt | awk -F '.' '{print $2}')
srvctl status database -d ${db_name}
Instance otcgr2ng1 is running on node scglvdoraci0009
Instance otcgr2ng2 is running on node scglvdoraci0010
```

What I did was using `crsctl` to get the database name. Obviously, **it would only work in your scenario that you have one database.**

> `CRSCTL` is an interface between you and Oracle Clusterware, parsing and calling Oracle Clusterware APIs for Oracle Clusterware objects. You can use CRSCTL commands to perform several operations such as Starting and stopping Oracle Clusterware resources, Enabling and disabling Oracle Clusterware daemons, Checking the health of the cluster, etc...

I remove the `mgmtdb` which is an internal database of the Grid Infrastructure. If you had more than one database in `Oracle RAC` , then

```
for db_name in $(crsctl stat res -t | grep ".db$" | grep -v mgmt | awk -F '.' '{print $2}')
do
echo $db_name
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The "crsctl" command give you the database unique name, not database name. These 2 can be different if this is a standby database.
You need to do srvctl (from RDBMS software) to get the database name. So, if the database unique name is different from database name (for example, in case of standby databases), you

So, use crstl to get the database unique name first:

$CRS_HOME/bin/crsctl stat res -t | grep ".db$" | grep -v mgmt | awk -F '.' '{print $2}'

**dbuniq_aws**

Then use srvctl to get the database name, using uppercase database unique name:

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/srvctl config database -d **DBUNIQ_AWS** | grep 'Database name:' | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d" " -f2

**DBUNIQ**

So as you see, the "srvctl config database" has information on the database name, as long as you have the database unique name information.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
srvctl config database